# Google Maps is disappear in iOS Flutter App after click Back button

Tags: ios, google-maps, flutter

I have a view (A) with some Text, Image and Google Maps inside. In this view has a Button "Go direction" to open Google Maps app by url_launcher (I'm using this one [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher)

The problem is when the user goes back from the Google Maps app, view A does not work properly anymore, Click on Back button from Top navigation bar the Maps and Images in A's view are disappear, just text content is still there.
User cannot go back to the previous view

This happens in iOS only, Android works well.
And it happens only if view A has the Maps inside

Comment: Have you resolved that issue?

Comment: There is no idea about it. I am using Statis Google Maps to show a Maps (as an Image)

Comment: The issue was solved in my app after I was extending the Widget containing the Map with "with WidgetsBindingObserver" and call "setState()" within didChangeAppLifecycleState()

Comment: @Thomas awesome, I will check it. Thanks